# Extract column from SQL table based on another column if the same table

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I m using POSTGRESQL.

Table of PURCHASES looks like this:

```
ID | CUSTOMER_ID | YEAR
1   1   2011
2   2   2012
3   2   2012
4   1   2013
5   3   2014
6   3   2014
7   3   2015
```

I need to extract **'ID'** of the purchase with the latest '**date/year**' for each CUSTOMER.

For example for CUSTOMER_ID 1 the year s 2013 which correcponds with id '**4**'.

I need to get ONE column as a return data structure.

PS. i m stuck with this kinda simple task )))

Comment: Edit your question and show the result set you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you want one row per customer, you can use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (customer_id) id
from purchases
order by customer_id, year desc;
```

This returns one column which is an `id` from the most recent year for that customer.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, but doesn't look too pretty...

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(CUSTOMER_ID) ID FROM PURCHASES P
WHERE (CUSTOMER_ID,YEAR) = 
(SELECT CUSTOMER_ID,MAX(YEAR) FROM PURCHASES WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = P.CUSTOMER_ID 
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID);
```

So for input

```
ID | CUSTOMER_ID | YEAR
1   1   2011
2   2   2012
3   2   2012
4   1   2013
5   3   2014
6   3   2014
7   3   2015
```

It will return

```
id
4
2
7

Meaning: 
For the lowest CUSTOMER_ID (it is 1) the id is 4 (year 2013)
Next we have CUSTOMER_ID (it is 2) the id is 2 (year 2012)
Lastly the CUSTOMER_ID (it is 3) the id is 7 (year 2015)
```

The idea behind this:

1. Group by CUSTOMER_ID
2. For each group select max(year)
3. While looping over all records - if Customer_id and year equals those from number 2. then select ID from this record.
4. Without DISTINCT ON(CUSTOMER_ID) it would return 2 records
   for CUSTOMER_ID = 2, because for both years 2012 it would find some records while looping.

If you write in the beginning instead of:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(CUSTOMER_ID) ID FROM PURCHASES P
```

this code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(CUSTOMER_ID) * FROM PURCHASES P
```

then you will see everything clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number()` analytic function with partition by `customer_id` to select by each customer with descending ordering by `year` ( if ties occur for `year` values [e.g. they're equal], then the below query brings the least `ID` values for each `customer_id`. e.g. `4`, `2`, `7` respectively )

```
WITH P2 AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_ID ORDER BY YEAR DESC) AS RN,
       *
  FROM PURCHASES 
)
SELECT ID FROM P2 WHERE RN = 1
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=32d4dce158222bbd9c0dc1cc45abb801)</kbd>